# Does HP factory reset wipe all connected hard drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a HP desktop computer(model 690-0039) that came with a m.2 SSD that had Windows installed on it(C:), plus a 1TB standard hard drive(labeled DATA), that has a recovery partition on it(labeled RECOVERY). I also added an additionnal 4TB hard drive inside

I want to upgrade the SSD and reinstall Windows 10 on it. I have seen the way to do this is to use HP recovery manager and do a factory reset.

However, I cant find answer to this nowhere; I have personnal files on the stock 1TB DATA HDD that I dont want to loose(the HDD is almost full.. so there is a lot of files and documents). By doing a factory reset, will that wipe the whole DATA drive? Or just recreate the RECOVERY partition on it? Also, what about the 4TB HDD I added? Will the factory reset wipe this HDD too if I dont unplug it prior to doing the factory reset with HP recovery software?

Id rather know if it doesnt wipe the whole DATA drive because backing it up will take.. a long time. so only if necessary

Thank you

Comment: *I have personal files on the DATA HDD that I don't want to lose* - you've got a backup, *right??*

Comment: Your secondary 4GB drive shouldn't get wiped. But if you want to be sure, unplug it before resetting. Seconding @Zac67 - if you haven't already backed up your critical data, now it's time to do so.

Comment: @Peregrino69 but what about the 1 TB HDD that came/was installed with the PC? Since there is a recovery partition on it, im guessing factory reset will setup the PC like it was originally, wich maybe means its gonna wipe that 1 TB HDD and create a new recovery partition on it? or will it just re-create the recovery partition without wiping the whole HDD? or maybe it wont do anything on this HDD at all? Thats why im confused and theres nowhere to find an answer to that even on HP website

Comment: "Does HP factory reset wipe all connected hard drives?" No, but you are advised to disconnect them during restore process.